# How to draw into tiled space?

Tags: svg, pen-tool, tiles

I want a pen that draws at 9 points spaced in a grid spaced about 90% of the page. In svg or similar vector format. The idea is to be able to make nice tile-able drawings.

I have tried photoshop, inkscape, sketch-pro. None seem to have this feature. I recall a drawing program ages ago that had this nice feature, but can not find it now.

Inkscape had a clone-tiles feature, but that seems to only clone existing objects, and I want to draw live.

Any help?

Comment: you might want to try out Illustrator's pattern editor features.

Comment: Vincent, sorry, should have said. My Illustrator is CS3, I am too broke (stingy) to buy new computer to run latest. Focussing on inkscape right now, still searching.